# Sable / shortbread proportions

Tags: baking, recipe-reverse-engineering

I’ve been on the hunt for a blank canvas sable / shortbread recipe for holiday cookies.

My ideal is a cut-and-bake type situation that holds its shape well.

I went though a fair few recipes and started tabulating the percentages of various ingredients.

From my reading I suspect that using confectioners sugar ( and a lower % of sugar overall) would give the properties I desire HOWEVER comparing two ‘similar’ recipes - the vanilla bean sable from Dories cookies, and the Tenderest Shortbread (which is actually a sable recipe) from baking with Dorie there is a huge difference: 48% vs 30%.

Can anyone help me understand these  differences, and what is most likely to give me the ideal cookie.